# Strange place for threading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm maintaining some existing pages and came across a bit of code from `System.Threading` and I'm not sure what to make of it.

(this is a the gist of it)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = GetFromCMS();
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/xpath/to/nodes");

    int i = 0;
    while (i < nodes.Count)
    {
        //do stuff with nodes[i]

        //last line in while loop - this is where I'm confused
        Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1);
    }
}
```

Does it makes sense to do something like this? Couldn't `i` be incremented ala `i++` instead? I'm not versed in multithreading, but given that there is *no other threading code* on this page and nothing really "special" happening (no extra threads being created, etc), it seems a little strange to me.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Math.Max is useless too, the whole thing can be rewritten to 'for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++){...}'

Comment: @SelflessCoder you are right, missed that refactoring too.

Comment: Looks like a cut and paste bug

Comment: looks like someone not knowing what they are doing!

Comment: @mitch there is so much garbage like this on our site from other, less careful devs. But thats the fun of it right? Finding a fixing these little gems?

Comment: @kaveman:
 Fun? I prefer code inspections! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your intuition is correct -- the code **is** a little strange, would probably make a good submission to [The DailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

I'm not sure of the original developers motives, but without any other context, the method appears to be threadsafe. You should be able to increment `i` using `i++;` with no risk.

Even better, you can eliminate `i` by rewriting as a `foreach` instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = GetFromCMS();
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/xpath/to/nodes");

    foreach(var node in nodes)
    {
        //do stuff with node
    }
}
```

Comment: great, that's what I thought! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`i` is a local variable (and not shared with any other threads), so a simple `i++` is safe.

So, replace this:

```
Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1);
```

with this

```
i++;
```

Or as a commenter pointed out, replace with a simple `for` or `foreach` loop!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are sharing the local `i` variable with other threads somehow (highly doubtful), `i++` would work just as well, without the overhead of the interlocking increment function.

The only way I could see that happening is if you are passing `i` by reference within the body of the loop to another function, which would then share it. If it's just used locally you are fine.

Comment: nope it's declared there locally, right before the `while` loop begins